20x32 pier and beam structure on clay soil. What spacing should I use?
I have a 20x32 tiny home I am planning.  Each beam consists of 2x10x20(2) and 2x10x12(2).  The 12 is butted up to the 20.  This is setup so there's a 4' overlap so that these things are sandwiched together tightly.  The ties are 4x4" adjustable ties.  This leaves me a 1" gap that I figure I could fill with a 1x12" shim.
The soil is clay and is at least that for 7'.  I want to do 12" sonotubes for the piers.  I would dig a 3 3/4' hole, fill 1/4' with pea gravel/crush rock, add a rebar square, and build up a 6" footer for the sonotube to sit on.  This gives me 1' of tube above the ground.  From what I understand, I can ask for a 3" slump and just pour directly into the tube without it rising up the outside of the tube.  This way I can pour the pier and footer at the same time.
This is my first time doing this so please point out any issues you might see.
Do I need this many tubes?
Do they have to be this close?
Partial Structure

24 piers

Beams


Rule of thumb says 2x10s are good for 10 foot open span.  Beams are usually 3 or 4 pieces(2x10s) side by side together.  Supports should be under joints in the beam.  A three piece 2x10 beam should be safer with supports at 12 ft(under joint) than a two piece beam.  Having a local engineer/building contractor/building inspector check this out is good idea.  Your local frost line level determines how deep to dig the tubes.

@crip659 I am in Houston so we don't have to deal with frost lines.

@crip659 So, could i use a 6" tie and have a pier every 10' where the beams butt up against each in the middle of the tie?
